# how to use Yii namespace

Tags: php, yii

I'm having I confusion in understanding the namespace from the Yii documentation as their are not enough example to understand, as I'm new to Yii framework please give some easy and detailed examples so that I can understand it's purpose.

Comment: Please give an example of what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: Jon, the documentation dont have any example for this and I had search alot but dont got anything related to Yii namespace that's why i posted here, if some one can just give one or two examples I may be able to understand this

Comment: did you read [this comment in the documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace#c3341)

Comment: @bool.dev: The only thing thats weird is that we have to refer to the `application` namespace when the folder is actually called `protected`.

Comment: This not show that I can import - in /config/main.php - a namespaced 3rd-party lib. E.g. I have a 3rd-party lib in namespace Rapid/Authorization, how to autoload this?

Comment: `Yii::setPathOfAlias('rapidauth', '..../Rapid/Authorization');` in cofig/main.php `..'controllerMap' => array(
        'rapidauthControl' => '\rapidauth\controllers....',
    ),...` sth like this , check the @bool.dev comment

Comment: which Yii are you using? the previous one doesn't have namespaces since they only came into PHP later, but you can 'fake' them using aliases like @sakhunzai said

Comment: Exactly, I made how @sakhunzai said. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may try read this documentation http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/en/basics.namespace
In general Yii namespaces - it is aliases for folders.
I.E.

```
  'aliases' => array(
            'frontend' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/frontend',
            'common' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/common',
            'backend' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/backend',
            'vendor' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/common/lib/vendor'
  ),

  ...

  'import' => array(
           'common.extensions.components.*',
           'common.components.*',
           'common.helpers.*',
           'common.models.*',
           'application.controllers.*',

// In result "common" = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..' . '/common'
```